# MySQL sum and add supplement charge Mathematic

Tags: mysql, sum

I got two columns in a MySQL table with Int values.

The column **kostnad** contains the price ex.200 and the column **paslag** contains the supplement charge the have the Int values from 0 to 20.

```
SELECT paslag,kostnad, 
SUM(case when "&_
         paslag = 0 then
        kostnad
         else
         paslag/kostnad*100+kostnad
    end ) AS totalt
FROM fakturor_massor
```

The error:
If i have two rows withe the following values:

```
kostnad   paslag
100       10
600       10
```

it returns this value:

711,6667 and not 770 that would be correct.I think i missed the procent class in school..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division should be the other way round:

```
SUM(case 
      when paslag = 0 then kostnad
      else kostnad/paslag*100 + kostnad
    end) AS totalt
```